# How to get instagram id from update 29/6/2020

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story, instagramapi-mgp25

I am building instagram in wordpress using the "elementor" plugin.
In the old version I used the => [https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[my-id]/media/recent/?access_token=[my-token]](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%5Bmy-id%5D/media/recent/?access_token=%5Bmy-token%5D)
Path to retrieve my instagram info data
Through the "29/6/2020" version the old link was no longer available. The algorithm changed that I was unable to retrieve my instagram data that way.
You can show me a new link or a new way for me to get my instagram data (photos, links, likes, comments) on my instagram.
Thank you very much
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to connect your instagram account with your facebook account. After of that you can access such things in new way as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media here. Also you need instagram account as Business account.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to fetch media from your personal account for your website you don't need to work with the graph API and Facebook login part, simply use the INSTAGRAM BASIC DISPLAY API and get your details and media.

Refer this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api